# Not able to open IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, startup, jetbrains-ide

I have tried restarting laptop but still not able to open.

[image: Giving the error while I am trying to open IntelliJ]

Comment: A commercial paid product like that should have its own customer support somewhere. This is a job for them. Stack Overflow is not the right place. Keep looking.

Comment: Try resolutions steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559-Start-Failed-Internal-error-recovering-IDE-to-the-working-state-after-the-critical-startup-error If the problem remains, please contact IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new